# How to Play Video using Node-Webkit?

Tags: html, html5-video, node-webkit

I'm using Node-Webkit, it's just a hello world program.
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Node Webkit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Node Webkit</h1>
    <video src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" controls></video>
</p>
</body>
</html>

{
  "name": "myapp.helloworldapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Hello Node webkit app",
  "main": "index.html",
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "chromium-args": "--load-plugin=ffmpegsumo.dll",
  "author": "richardmtp@gmail.com",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

And I Run the program using following `D:\...\nw\nw.exe D:\...\helloWorld\app.v1.nw`.

Then the screen appear as follows, please find attached image

[image: output-image]

But not playing & the play button also disabled

1. And I include ffmpegsumo.dll in nw Root folder

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML for playing videos looks ok but the problem is that out-of-the-box NW doesn't support MP3/MP4 and many other formats, so you need to replace the stock ffmpeg.dll with one from here...

https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases

Answer (score 0):

You can refer link below for your issue:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-&-MP4-(H.264)-using-the--video--&--audio--tags.

Comment: I played the videos, and this is my another problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021984/how-to-play-next-video-using-javascript-in-node-webkit) please help me to find problem, thank you.